# Managing API calls with default error handling in react-redux application

Tags: redux, axios, redux-thunk

I've completed my application and I'm now integrating the real api calls for each async action. I use `redux-thunk` which returns a promise from an `axios` instance.

Currently I'm repeating so much of the same logic in my actions that I'm sure I'm missing something.

**API response example**

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "warnings": [],
    "errors": [],
    "response": {/* stuff */}
}
```

The Idea is that I need the same error handling if either the `axios` call fails (so another response status then 2xx). Additionally I need to also do the same thing when the api response returns `"ok": false`.

Preferably I would like to dispatch an action which shows a notification to users so they also know when something goes wrong. Aside from that I want to log the api response's `warnings` and `error` entities. This is mainly because I'll use [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) for monitoring.

Any Ideas on how to do this without doing a `.catch()` with the same logic on each api call in any of my action creators?

I've thought about using the `onError` of `axios` but that can't dispatch an action as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [response interceptor](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors) to dispatch appropriate actions.  Just wire them up after you create the store

```
const store = createStore(...)

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (!response.data.ok) {
    store.dispatch({ type: "RESPONSE_NOT_OK", response }
  }

  return response
}, (error) => {
  store.dispatch({ type: "RESPONSE_HAD_ERROR", error }

  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Obviously, you can handle the response how ever you want, this was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any way to also pass down an api call specific param to the interceptor for when things go bad or not?

Comment: Can you give me an example of an api call specific param?  Both the `response` and the `error` params in the callbacks have a `request` field which is the request that generated the response.  [Here is the docs on what is available on that](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config).

Comment: Basically I would like to provide a "message" param to my interceptor so the interceptor can pass it to the action which creates a notification displaying the message to the user. So for login it could be "failed to login" but for creating a post it could be "failed to create post" etc. Hope this is clear :)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I suspect any additional values added to the [request config](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config) (e.g. `axios.get('/example', { myValue: "test" })`) will be accessible in the intercepts on the request field (e.g. `response.request.myValue`).  Give it a shot and let me know how it goes.